# C++ What does delete pointer,pointer=0; statement work ? Does it clear memory twice?

Tags: c++

```
int *ptr = new int(10);    
printf("%d \n",*ptr);    
delete ptr,ptr=0;    
printf("%d",ptr);
```

Output:
10
0

My question here is how this statment "delete ptr,ptr = 0" works ?  Does it free the memory twice ?

Comment: int(10) is wrong. if you want to allocate memory for 10 int's then do it int *ptr= new int[10];

Comment: But if you want to create one int with the value 10, `new int(10)` is fine.

Comment: and ptr of 1st printf is showing the value of the variable to which it is pointing to and ptr of 2nd printf is showing the memory address of ptr.

Comment: @KhairulBasarRofi: It allocates space for *one* integer, with `10` as its value. It is not an array, nor intended to be one.

Comment: I would like to create one only int value.

Comment: i thought he wanted to allocate memory for 10 int's.

Comment: It's quite personal, but i usually prefer NULL (or even better: nullptr) rather than 0 to indicate a null pointer. I find that more explicit and more "standard".

Answer (score 4):

The pointer and the memory the pointer points to are 2 different things.
Setting the pointer to 0 after you delete it is just an added safety mechanism to ensure you don't try to use a memory address that you shouldn't.

`int *ptr = new int(10);`

ptr will have a value like 0xabcd1234, but *ptr will be 10
You can "do stuff" with the memory address 0xabcd1234 because it's allocated to you.

`printf("%d \n",*ptr);`
`delete ptr,ptr=0;`

delete ptr "gives back" the memory, but you still have it's address (that's dangerous_.
ptr = 0 means you forget the address, so all is good.

I guess the "trick" is the comma operator: `delete ptr,ptr=0;` which as other have said means "do the left hand part, then the right hand part." If you try to get a result (`int i_know_it_is_a_stupid_example = 10,20;` the result is the RHS [20])

Comment: It doesn't just "forget the address", but also assigns it specifically to the sentinel [`NULL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer) (`0`) value, often used to indicate that the pointer does not point to a valid object.  `NULL` can be used for this purpose because it is guaranteed to never be a valid address.

Comment: Back in the olden days we had a box of zeros and ones that we used to hammer into a long metal tube to write programs. In those days our HP machine had a specific compiler option that meant you could read *0 (it always returned 0) and write to 0 (which was a NOP). We never knew the option was turned on by our makefile until we ported to SunOS and started crashing all over the place ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
delete ptr
```

Frees the memory at the address pointed to by `ptr`. However, `ptr` still points to that memory address.

```
ptr = 0
```

`ptr` no longer points to a specific memory address.

Therefore, the point of `ptr = 0` is to enable the programmer to test whether the pointer is still usable (in use). If you don't set `ptr = 0`, but only `delete ptr`, `ptr` will still point to a location in memory which may contain garbage information.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't. In C++, it's [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) . Quote from wiki:

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator
>   (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its
>   first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second
>   operand and returns this value (and type).

Therefore, in that statement

```
delete ptr, ptr = 0;
```

is equivalent to

```
delete ptr; // executed first, its return value is ignored
ptr = 0;    // the return value of '=', which is '0' is returned by ',' operator
```

Comment: Good on explaining the comma operator, but a bit to terse to properly explain what the it that won't is.

Answer (score 1):

Frees the memory, then nulls the pointer so no-one could get confused that the pointer is still pointing at a valid location. Note that `x, y` is evaluated the same as `x; y`, the only difference being that the former doesn't work with statements (and is an expression, itself).

Answer (score 0):

The statement `delete ptr` will make the pointer become the `overhang pointer`. This stands for you can't use the pointer anymore, but now actually it still point to a valid memory address. So you need to use `ptr=0` for making it be a `nullptr`. This is always a safe way to use the `ptr`. I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Delete ptr will free up dynamically allocated memory, whereas ptr=0 makes sure that pointer is now a "null" pointer so you dont get any weird/unexpected behavior